# Is Category of schemes locally small?

Tags: schemes, group-schemes

One can use Yoneda lemma in the context of locally small category. due to yoneda lemma, we can consider a scheme X as a functor of points. (like SpecA $\mapsto$ X(A)=Hom(SpecA, X) ). but I don't know that a scheme category is locally small. I guess the scheme category is not locally small. This curiocity comes out when I study group scheme theory. Yoneda lemma can be applied to only group scheme over a field k? Please feel free to write your opinion. Thank you.

Comment: In fact the category of schemes is locally small. But local-smallness is not really crucial to the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: To get a functor from category of schemes to Category of Sets, X(Y) = Mor (Y, X) should be a set.  Locally-smallness is crucial to yoneda lemma.  Is something wrong? and can i get a reference for this issue?

Comment: It is not crucial in the sense that you can adjust the statement and the proof still works. In this case you replace “set” with something else if you have something not locally small. Put it another way, the Yoneda lemma is robust and easily generalised.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can I get a reference for generalized yoneda lemma? I still google but can't find any info.

Comment: That’s because it’s nothing profound or difficult. If you read the usual proof you will see what I mean. I think Mac Lane is basically making this point when he talks about the category Ens instead of Set.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. best regards!